# Advertisement in XNA windows games (not Windows Phone 7)

Tags: xna, ads

What existing services/libraries are there for in-game advertisement that can be used in your XNA games on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to rely on donations outside of the Xbox 360 and use the XLIG for distributing on the xbox 360.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to advertise in xbox360 then you are out of luck. You will have to manually do this, in a way that will still allow to pass peer review (subtly).

And even so, it's not like a user can click the ad, so how would the ad place know how much to charge you?

Comment: Apparently you don't have Internet-access on the Xbox 360, so we can exclude that entirely.

Comment: well you have internet access on the xbox (xbox live), but no browser capabilities.  Some major AAA games have online leaderboards, but I believe you would need a special nod from microsoft to do that